# Add online meeting url to event with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Could anybody help me with creating an event with Microsoft Graph API.

Desirable behavior is to add a link to the event which is clickable in majority of the calendar clients. 
Here is an example of the event payload I’ve used:

```
{
    ...
    "body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "<a href=\"https://somelink.com\">Start Online Meeting</a>"
    },
    "onlineMeetingUrl": "https://somelink.com"
}
```

This payload is sent as POST request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events`

current response is:

```
{ 
 ...
 'onlineMeetingUrl': null,
 ...
}
```

and details of the event are not clickable in the calendar app
and displayed like plain text

`Start Online Meeting`

or is converted to

`Start Online Meeting <https://somelink.com>`

in Google calendar

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['onlineMeetingUrl' is null after call Create Event in Graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143347/onlinemeetingurl-is-null-after-call-create-event-in-graph-api)

Comment: Are you inviting the Gmail user?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try escaping double quotes character in value of Content property and wrap the anchor tag in div element? Example below:

`{
  "body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "<div><a href=\"http://bing.com\">bing</a></div>"
  }
}`

Comment: having the same issue, escaping the quotes solves the display issue but it doesn't solve the onlinemeetingurl response that stays null