# 'onlineMeetingUrl' is null after call Create Event in Graph api

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I use [create event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_events) api to create an event object with "onlineMeetingUrl: https://meet.lync.com/example/joyce/NLSD7Y62" but the response of "onlineMeetingUrl" is null.

Is it a bug or is there any way to create a new event with 'onlineMeetingUrl'?

Here are my test steps.

Step 1. `POST /me/events`

```
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"BfXylo4WykyAenTZICXL5AAApUQ11g==\"",
    "id": "AAMkADVmMzE2MjY0LTZkOGYtNGI4MS1iNWMxLTljYzg3MWY5MWQxMQBGAAAAAABZMfR36TVMQ6yunaqZPvVRBwAF9fKWjhbKTIB6dNkgJcvkAAAAAAENAAAF9fKWjhbKTIB6dNkgJcvkAAClFy2jAAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2018-03-07T02:31:20.6459109Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-07T02:31:24.2554747Z",
    "changeKey": "BfXylo4WykyAenTZICXL5AAApUQ11g==",
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "Taipei Standard Time",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "Taipei Standard Time",
    "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000E5DACD60BCB5D301000000000000000010000000A65419D96CF4C347B8B3B5A340753291",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": true,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Sky Meeting",
    "bodyPreview": "Join online meeting",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAMkADVmMzE2MjY0LTZkOGYtNGI4MS1iNWMxLTljYzg3MWY5MWQxMQBGAAAAAABZMfR36TVMQ6yunaqZPvVRBwAF9fKWjhbKTIB6dNkgJcvkAAAAAAENAAAF9fKWjhbKTIB6dNkgJcvkAAClFy2jAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
    "onlineMeetingUrl": "https://meet.lync.com/example/joyce/NLSD7Y62",
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "Join online meeting"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2018-03-08T00:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2018-03-08T00:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "Online meeting"
    },
    "recurrence": null,
    "attendees": [],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Joyce",
            "address": "joyce@example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2. The onlineMeetingUrl in the response event object is null.

```
{
    ...
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onlineMeetingUrl` property is not writable. We will update the documentation to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: As of 23/6/2018 this is still documented as writable (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#event). If onlineMeetingUrl is going to remain effectively unusable can it please be removed from the REST API documentation, thnx.

Comment: Are there any updates on this? `onlineMeetingUrl` is still shown as a writable field when creating an event. I'm currently storing this as a extended property, but your only able to get these fields if you're the organizer of the event.

Comment: Sorry for the lag in updating the documentation. The MSDN documentation is undergoing a migration to the learn.microsoft.com platform which has caused some delay here.

Comment: Online Meeting url is auto generated, it is not expected to be writeable and as expected not all extended properties are Transferred along with the meeting invite attendees.

Comment: I updated the Microsoft Graph documentation to clarify the behavior of onlineMeetingUrl in the event entity: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/2974/files#diff-71f5763065137c0de44916af48685785

Comment: Also in the event update topic: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/2974/files#diff-606448471245858ac99784d5029bffaf

Answer (score 0):

Add these params in the request body

```
"isOnlineMeeting": true,
"onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
```

Answer (score 0):

onlineMeetingUrl is null in response even while passing "isOnlineMeeting": true,
"onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).